# VBA - Find all values on column B for article on column A and place them to a single row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very large Excel document (20k entries) with data similar to this:

```
ARTICLE     TIME
article 1   1s
article 1   2s
article 2   1s
article 2   2s
article 2   3s
...
```

I need to extract the unique values from the articles column and place their corresponding time values on a single row, like this:

```
ARTICLE     TIMES
article 1   1s  2s
article 2   1s  2s  3s
...
```

I tried with formulas (INDEX, MATCH, FIND etc...) but I didn't get any proper results.

How can I do this using VBA (maybe?)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code in Before Click event:

```
cnt = 8
For i = 2 To 6
strg = strg & Cells(i, 2)
If Cells(i, 1) <> Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
Cells(cnt, 1) = Cells(i, 1)
Cells(cnt, 2) = strg
strg = ""
cnt = cnt + 1
End If
Next
```

The time values are populated in a single cell against each Article

Comment: Ah, yes. It worked.
I modified it a bit to check for the last row (instead of 8) and to ad a space between characters, so I can do a "text to columns".
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recipe without using VBA

1. build aggregated TIMES for each article

   ```
   ARTICLE   TIME    SAME                 TIMES
   article 1 1s      =if(A3=A2;"YES";"")  =B2
   article 1 2s      =if(A3=A2;"YES";"")  = if(A3=A2;Concatenate(B3;" ";D2);B3)
   article 1 3s      =if(A4=A3;"YES";"")  = if(A4=A3;Concatenate(B4;" ";D3);B4)
   article 2 1s      (extend the formulas down to the end of range)
   ```
2. Create a copy, replacing the formulas in SAME and TIMES by the result
   select columns C and D
   menu -> copy 
   select columns C and D agin
   menu -> paste special ; values only
3. Sort the list by "SAME" (this will put all "YES" in a single block)
4. Remove all SAME="YES" columns
5. Sort back to ascending list of articles
6. Remove "TIME" and "YES" columns

Done.

Comment: OK, so this might be a way to take it...
However, if I use the formulas like you specified, I get something like this:

`ARTICLE  TIME SAME TIMES
ARTICLE 1 1s YES 1s
ARTICLE 1 2s YES 2s 1s
ARTICLE 2 1s  1s
ARTICLE 2 2s YES 2s 1s
ARTICLE 2 3s YES 3s 2s 1s`

And if I remove all the SAME="YES" rows I don't get the right data... And I will only need to keep the last row, the one with all the times...